# Defining a variable between two points with a datetime pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a pandas dataframe, and I want to calculate a variable based on certain hours of the day. I already pulled the hours as integers out of the datetime series. When I write my conditional statements between two hours and execute my script, I get the warning `"The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"`

When I put in `any()` or `all()` in my script, the script runs but it doesn't calculate the value between the two hours. I just get back a value that is not in the conditions. Can anyone help me out?

Here is my code so far

```
METdata = pd.read_csv('C:\Schoolwork\GEOL 701s_HW1\MET_station\MET_Data_3.26_hourly.csv', infer_datetime_format = True, na_values = '', header = [1], skiprows = [2, 3], index_col = [0])
hour = METdata.index.hour

NET_rad_Wm2 = np.array(METdata['NR_Wm2_Avg'])
Nr = NET_rad_Wm2 * 0.0036
g_day = Nr * 0.1
g_night = Nr * 0.5

def func(hour):
    if ((hour > 8) and (hour < 17)):
        return g_night
    else:
        return g_day
g = func(hour)
```

Comment: Please post your `hour` , `g_night` and `g_day` code

Comment: I added those parts of my code.

Comment: what do you expect `g` to be?

Comment: I want `g` to be a float array that I can use in a calculation later in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a series as return, then you just need to call `apply` instead of calling the function directly

```
hour.apply(func)
```